# Is Captain Picard smiling at a Ferengi joke out of character?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, ferengi, jean-luc-picard

Early in "The Perfect Mate," a Ferengi, Par Lenor, accosts Captain Picard and Ambassador Briam. One of the quips of Lenor is that

> Peace is good for trade---unless you happen to be an arms merchant

After a few seconds, Captain Picard smiles and walks away with the ambassador. It seems as though Picard is smiling because he finds the joke funny.

I wonder if this is a goof by Patrick Stewart. Picard is normally stoic, and though he does smile, you'd think that smiling at a joke made by a Ferengi would not be high on his list of things to do.

Though it is possible that the script has Picard smiling. He's not a robot, after all.

Comment: Picard has never been a great fan of the Ferengi, he may be smiling in a diplomatic manner, ie "I'm going to smile and walk away because if I don't I may say something I'll regret"

Comment: The script  says ***Picard steps in, trying to help the ambassador avoid  the headaches he knows a Ferengi invariably brings...*** I would assume he's merely smiling politely.

Comment: That statement is actually not a joke, but an insight, Picard is maybe smiling because he didn’t expect such wisdom from a Ferengi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/221.txt) doesn't exactly address Picard's *smile*, but it does give us some insight into his feelings in this scene; annoyed and slightly embarrassed. He's certainly not amused by the Ferengi's antics.

I'll remove the dialogue

> Par Lenor suddenly appears in front of them... delaying the
> Ambassador's exit...
>
> **Picard steps in, trying to help the ambassador avoid the headaches he
> knows a Ferengi invariably brings...**
>
> Picard moves the Ambassador down the corridor... the Ferengi
> follows...
>
> At the turbolift, **Picard waits impatiently for the lift to arrive...
> shoots Geordi a look as the Ferengi continues to drill the
> Ambassador...**
>
> The turbolift doors finally open... as Picard ushers in Briam...
>
> Picard gives Geordi a grateful look as he says...
>
> The door closes in the Ferengi's face.

As you can see, It's only because Picard is a seasoned diplomat and is trying to avoid making a scene that he humours the Ferengi's request to speak to the Ambassador. His smile (and indeed his whole demeanour) is a studied attempt to avoid openly expressing his extremely visible dissatisfaction at Par Lenor's presence and actions. When the opportunity arises, he makes a sharp exit.